# How do I get my code from emacs into the unix server?

Tags: unix, command

I have written some code in emacs, and now I am trying to get it into my directory through a secure shell to my school's unix mainframe. What commands do I need?

the directory is:
~/1730/homework/binder_proj1

and the files I need to put in there are:
Program1Math.h
Program1Math.cpp
Program1.cpp

I know this is probably really simple, but I'm a first-time unix-user and advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you use SCP, be sure to checkout how to do ssh-keygen/public key authentication, so you don't have to manually re-authorize (enter your password.) each time you do one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out scp? Here is the [man page for scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) and a nice [set of examples](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

What usually works is something like this...

```
scp -r ~/1730/homework/binder_proj1 <username>@<server>:/path/to/dest/
```

Comment: that seems right, but what should I list as the username and server? I am operating from my macbook and the path to the file is /Users/katelynbinder/ComputerScience/1730/homework1